# Regex format from PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Can you please help me. How can I add this regex `(?<=^|\s):d(?=$|\s)` in javascript RegExp?

e.g

```
regex = new RegExp("?????" , 'g');
```

I want to replace the emoticon `:d`, but only if it is surrounded by spaces (or at an end of the string).

Comment: regex = new RegExp("(?<=^|\s):d(?=$|\s)" , 'g');
This line gives me the error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=^|s):d(?=$|s)/: Invalid group

Comment: I've tried but the error still exist. And one more thing is that I want to modify the center characters ":d" each time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, as Some1.Kill.The.DJ mentioned, I recommend you use the literal syntax to create the regular expression:

```
var pattern = /yourPatternHere/g;
```

It's shorter, easier to read and you avoid complications with escape sequences.

The reason why the pattern does not work is that JavaScript does not support lookbehinds (`(?<=...)`. So you have to find a workaround for that. You won't get around including that character in your pattern:

```
var pattern = /(?:^|\s):d(?!\S)/g;
```

Since there is no use in capturing anything in your pattern anyway (because `:d` is fixed) you are probably only interested in the position of the match. That means, when you find a match, you will have to check whether the first character is a space character (or is not `:`). If that is the case you have to increment the position by `1`. If you know that your input string can never start with a space, you can simply increment any found position if it is not `0`.

Note that I simplified your lookahead a bit. That is actually the beauty of lookarounds that you do not have to distinguish between end-of-string and a certain character type. Just use the negative lookahead, and assure that there is no non-space character ahead.

Just for future reference that means you could have simplified your initial pattern to:

```
(?<!\S):d(?!\S)
```

(If you were using a regex engine that supports lookbehinds.)

**EDIT:**

After your comment on the other answer, it's actually a lot easier to use the workaround. Just write back the captured space-character:

```
string = string.replace(/(^|\s):d(?!\S)/g, "$1emoticonCode");
```

Where `$1` refers to what was matched with `(^|\s)`. I.e. if the match was at the beginning of the string `$1` will be empty, and if there was a space before `:d`, then `$1` will contian that space character.

Answer (score 1):

`Javascript` doesnt support `lookbehind` i.e`(?<=)`..

It supports `lookahead`

Better use

```
/(?:^|\s)(:d)(?=$|\s)/g
```

`Group1` captures required match

Comment: JavaScript does not support lookbehinds

Comment: @m.buettner so stupid of me to forget that..edited the ans..thxx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My goal is to replace the emoticon :D with an icon! But i want to replace it only in case of individual words! eg fjkdshk:)jhds. Your modified regex unfortunaly dont work as expected and replace only if the text starts with that symbol

Comment: @George that is vital information for how to use the workaround. see the edit of my answer

Comment: @m.buettner as always..ur ans is comprehensive and to the point..;)